# Saliency maps in Keras in a network with an embedding layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras, differentiation

I want to implement saliency maps using LSTM with an embedding layer in Keras. So basically I want to implement an differentiation function of output from a final layer with respect to input. Here is the code where I'm defining my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, 32, dropout=0.5))
model.add(LSTM(32, dropout_W=0.5, dropout_U=0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy']
```

I would be grateful if someone could help in this task.

Comment: Hi, could you solve your problem?
I was trying using this function: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1777#issuecomment-250040309. However I was not able to solve the Theano error I get there in my github comment.